# cout << string(pattern.length() - i - 1, ' ') i did not understand this line

Tags: c++

```
//code to write a pyramid with input from user

#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string pattern {};
    cout << "Enter string: ";
    getline(cin, pattern);

    int i {}, j {}, k {};
    for(i = 0; i < pattern.length(); ++i) {
        cout << string(pattern.length() - i - 1, ' '); // display leading spaces
        for(j = 0; j < i + 1; ++j) // display left side
            cout << pattern.at(j);

        for(k = i - 1; k >= 0; k--) // display right side
            cout << pattern.at(k);

        cout << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: If you don't know what a function (a constructor in this case) does, take a look at the [reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/basic_string)

Answer (score 1):

This line:

```
cout << string(pattern.length() - i - 1, ' '); // display leading spaces
```

uses the string [constructor](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/basic_string) that takes a count, and a `char`. The result is a string containing the `char` repeated count times. e.g.

```
cout << string(4, 'a');
```

will result in:

```
aaaa
```

Answer (score 0):

It returns a string made of `pattern.length() - i - 1` whitespaces.

> `fill (6) string (size_t n, char c);`
>
> (6) fill constructor
> Fills the string with n consecutive copies of character c.

[string::string - C++ Reference](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/string/)

Answer (score 0):

```
cout << string(pattern.length() - i - 1, ' '); // display leading spaces
```

This line will display the spaces needed before starting the pattern on each line. Suppose your pattern length is 3. So, on the first line, it will display a string having spaces equal to `3-0-1=2`, and then the pattern will print. Similarly, it will go on for rest of iteration.

---

Here `string()` is a constructor, which can take 2 parameters. The syntax is -

```
string (size_t n, char c);
```

The first one being the string length of the string to be constructed using character `c` and the second one will be the character itself using which you want to build the string.

---

If you are not comfortable using that, you can consider that line of code doing something equivalent to the following code -

```
for(j = 0 ; j < pattern.length() - i - 1 ; j++) // prints spaces in each iteration 
    cout << ' ';
```

You can use the `string()` way instead if you want to print a character certain number of times rather than looping over. It will make your code shorter.

```
int main()
{
    string pattern {};       // initialises pattern with empty string
    cout << "Enter string: ";
    getline(cin, pattern);   // takes user input into pattern

    int i {}, j {}, k {};    

    // We will loop for pattern.length() times
    for(i = 0; i < pattern.length(); ++i) { 

        // In each iteration, first print required number of leading spaces
        // So, string(pattern.length() - i - 1, ' ') will initialise a string with required number of spaces and print it
        cout << string(pattern.length() - i - 1, ' '); // display leading spaces
        // Once spaces are printed, we print i+1 characters from pattern starting from 0th index of pattern
        for(j = 0; j < i + 1; ++j) // display left side
            cout << pattern.at(j);
          
        // We will now print i characters from pattern, this time starting from i-1th index
        for(k = i - 1; k >= 0; k--) // display right side
            cout << pattern.at(k);

        cout << endl;
    }
}
```

Eg. suppose input is `*-*-*`. So output will be as follows -

```
    *        // i=0 : 1st loop prints 5-0-1=4 spaces, 2nd loop prints 0 to 0+1=1 characters from pattern, i.e, * and 3rd loop doesn't run on this iteration
   *-*       // i=1 : 1st loop prints 5-1-1=3 spaces, 2nd loop prints 0 to 2 characters, ie, *- and 3rd loop prints (1-1)th index till 0th index of pattern which is 0th index,i.e, *
  *-*-*      // i=2 : 1st loop prints 5-2-1=2 spaces, 2nd loop prints 0 to 3 characters, ie *-* and 3rd loop prints (2-1)th index till 0th index, ie 1st and 0th index of pattern,i.e, -*
 *-*-*-*     // Similar process as above
*-*-*-*-*    // Similar process as above
```

Hope this makes sense now :)

Comment: Can you please explain me the code...I am a new learner..and i am finding it difficult to understand the code..that would be of great help..thanks..

Comment: @NoopurBaranwal which part of code you didn't understand?

Comment: @NoopurBaranwal I have made edits and commented each line of code. Check to see if you understand it now

Comment: Thank u so much Abhishek..finally i understood it,,:-)

Comment: Some hair are definitely going to turn grey understanding and writing these codes..:-)

Comment: @NoopurBaranwal Glad to help! You can accept my answer if it helped :)

Comment: @NoopurBaranwal, start by thinking on your own what the code needs to do when outputting such a pattern. I always feel that's much easier than understanding code from others/online resources and only then refer for help

Comment: will try writing on my own,Thanks for the help again.will ask if i need help again.